# Make sun move witgh keyboards input

Tags: python, animation, graphics

I'm using python graphics (john Zelle's) and I have this simple code so far

```
from Graphics import *
 
def main():
 sun = Circle(Point(200, 100), 80)
     sun.setFill("yellow")
     sun.draw(win)
main()
```

I need to get keyboard input to place the sun at specific coordinates on the screen. For example

```
Time = int(input("Enter a time: "))
```

Then when the user enters a time like 8,5,3...
The sun I drew in the graphics window will move to the level of time it was inputted, 5 can be midday so the sun is in the middle of the screen.

Comment: You might need to be more specific about your data ranges and which "middle" you mean.  Does the sun go up/down?  Left/right?  Does it follow an arc?  Is it from the perspective of northern or southern hemisphere?  (e.g. which direction are you looking?)  What's your field of view?  Does apparent position get affected by atmospheric effects?  What is the radius of your planet and what is the viewer's height above sea level?  Are you needing to simulate our actual sun and earth (using date, time, latitude and longitude)?

Comment: No, my codes supposed to be very simple. Only going up and down. But IDK how to actually get keyboard input to make it affect the sun, that's basically the question.

Comment: So... do you know how to get a keyboard input?

Comment: You can use a variable for your sun's Y position.  For example `100 - 10 * Time` would give you something between 0 and 100 if your `Time` variable contains a number between 0 and 10.  Maybe you're looking for something similar.  If you need it to be symmetric around the value 5, then scale something like `abs(Time - 5)`.  If you need to make it more like the actual sun, then drive a sine or cosine function with something in the right range.  Sounds like you're fundamentally asking a basic math question, not really anything about programming specifically.

Comment: hmm... i'll see what I can do. Thankss

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.